# XML Explicit Breakdown and Addition Issue

Tags: sql, ssms, ssms-2012

So I currently have some `FOR XML EXPLICIT` SQL statement written and it's going pretty well except for 2 things I'm encountering

When I try to add this extra 4 tag tier - it simply adds this  PatientData at the bottom of the Chase section rather than drop within each individual chase

As below

```
<ChaseRequests dtGenerated="Friday, January 30, 2015 5:24:39 PM">
  <Chases>
    <Chase id="12345">
      <PracticeId><![CDATA[82791]]></PracticeId>
      <AccountId><![CDATA[8279101]]></AccountId>
      <RequestingCompany><![CDATA[DERP]]></RequestingCompany>
    </Chase>
    <Chase id="12346">
      <PracticeId><![CDATA[82791]]></PracticeId>
      <AccountId><![CDATA[8279101]]></AccountId>
      <RequestingCompany><![CDATA[DERP]]></RequestingCompany>
      <PatientData />
      <PatientData />
    </Chase>
  </Chases>
</ChaseRequests>
```

As you can see the Patient Data tags appear at the bottom where I would like to see it under both "RequestingCompany" tags for each ChaseID section.

In addition to that I want to insert two lone tags under the "ChaseRequests" tag up top

```
<Vendor Id = 'Derp'/>
<Request Id = 'Herp'/>
```

But I'm totally unsure how to do that @_@

My code so far...

```
SELECT 
    tag,
    parent,
    [ChaseRequests!1!dtGenerated],
    [Chases!2!],
    [Chase!3!id],
    [Chase!3!PracticeId!CData],
    [Chase!3!AccountId!CData],
    [Chase!3!RequestingCompany!CData],
    [PatientData!4!Element]
FROM (SELECT
    1 Tag,
    NULL Parent,
    'Friday, January 30, 2015 5:24:39 PM' as [ChaseRequests!1!dtGenerated],
    NULL as [Chases!2!],
    NULL as [Chase!3!id],
    NULL as [Chase!3!PracticeId!CData],
    NULL as [Chase!3!AccountId!CData],
    NULL as [Chase!3!RequestingCompany!CData],
    NULL as [PatientData!4!Element]
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    2 Tag,
    1 Parent,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    3 Tag,
    2 Parent,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    c.ChartID,
    '82791',
    '8279101',
    'DERP',
    NULL
FROM Charts c 
WHERE ChartID in (12345,12346)
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    4 Tag,
    3 Parent,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL
FROM Charts c 
WHERE ChartID in (12345,12346)
) X
FOR XML EXPLICIT
```

And my ideal outcome...

```
<ChaseRequests dtGenerated="Friday, January 30, 2015 5:24:39 PM">
    <Vendor ID="Derp"/>
    <Request ID="Herp"/>
  <Chases>
    <Chase id="12345">
      <PracticeId><![CDATA[82791]]></PracticeId>
      <AccountId><![CDATA[8279101]]></AccountId>
      <RequestingCompany><![CDATA[DERP]]></RequestingCompany>
      <PatientData />
    </Chase>
    <Chase id="12346">
      <PracticeId><![CDATA[82791]]></PracticeId>
      <AccountId><![CDATA[8279101]]></AccountId>
      <RequestingCompany><![CDATA[DERP]]></RequestingCompany>
      <PatientData />
    </Chase>
  </Chases>
</ChaseRequests>
```

Just for reference - I plan to drop more nested tags within that PatientData tag - I just want the PatientData tag to appear within each "Chase" area

Any info would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

`FOR XML EXPLICIT` processes the rows *in order*, so you have to impose an order on the rows that matches their hierarchical relations.  Like so:

```
SELECT
    tag,
    parent,
    [ChaseRequests!1!dtGenerated],
    [Chases!2!],
    [Chase!3!id],
    [Chase!3!PracticeId!CData],
    [Chase!3!AccountId!CData],
    [Chase!3!RequestingCompany!CData],
    [PatientData!4!Element]
FROM (SELECT 
    1 Tag,
    NULL Parent,
    'Friday, January 30, 2015 5:24:39 PM' as [ChaseRequests!1!dtGenerated],
    NULL as [Chases!2!],
    NULL as [Chase!3!id],
    NULL as [Chase!3!PracticeId!CData],
    NULL as [Chase!3!AccountId!CData],
    NULL as [Chase!3!RequestingCompany!CData],
    NULL as [PatientData!4!Element]
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    2 Tag,
    1 Parent,
    'Friday, January 30, 2015 5:24:39 PM',
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    3 Tag,
    2 Parent,
    'Friday, January 30, 2015 5:24:39 PM',
    NULL,
    c.ChartID,
    '82791',
    '8279101',
    'DERP',
    NULL
FROM Charts c 
WHERE ChartID in (12345,12346)
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    4 Tag,
    3 Parent,
    'Friday, January 30, 2015 5:24:39 PM',
    NULL,
    c.ChartID,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL
FROM Charts c 
WHERE ChartID in (12345,12346)
) X
order by [ChaseRequests!1!dtGenerated],
    [Chases!2!],
    [Chase!3!id],
    Tag
FOR XML EXPLICIT
```

Note: This will only get more complicated the deeper you go.  You really should consider switching to `PATH` or `AUTO` to make it easier on yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the input! And this definitely helped out my nesting issue - not sure if you could help me out with that "Additional" two lines I need to get in there as well.  

And I would definitely use XML PATH if I could keep my CDATA tags :(